# reading data from file and printing specific colums per line

Tags: python, list, file, python-3.x

I have a CSV file containing data in the following format without a header:

12345;TO-345;Something;Might be useful as well;etc;44444:33333;and_so_on;

1435;TO-345;Something as well;Definately useful;etc;44444:33333;done;

And the file goes for another 1000 lines or so.

What I'm trying to accomplish with Python is that I want to read the file line by line and be able to call specific columns per line. For example when the column specific for-loop starts with line 0, it could print out the data in column 0 and then continue doing the same for next line all the way to the end of the file (last line).  I have found good examples for similar scenarios but have failed to understand the thing to do exactly what I want.

Comment: Can you add an example of the output you are trying to achieve?

Comment: `print row[0]`, `print row[1]`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract the information from the file, you could use the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module.

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open("data.txt", "r") as f:
...   reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=";")
...   for row in reader:
...     print(row)
... 
['12345', 'TO-345', 'Something', 'Might be useful as well', 'etc', '44444:33333', 'and_so_on', '']
['1435', 'TO-345', 'Something as well', 'Definately useful', 'etc', '44444:33333', 'done', '']
```

(I took your sample and put it in `data.txt`)

In the inner loop, you could select any column you want, the rows are just lists of strings. To get the third column you’d print `print(row[2])` instead of the whole row.

Alternatively, you can also first load all rows into a list, if you want to loop over it multiple times:

```
import csv

def load_data(filename):
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=";")
        return list(reader)

data = load_data("data.txt")
for row in data:
    print(row[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start with a simple python code like

```
file = open('filename', 'r');
for line in file:
    row = line.split(';')
    print(row[1])
file.close()
```

This will print second column from each line of file.